# How can I simplify multiple uses of BigInt::from()?

Tags: rust

I wrote a program where I manipulated a lot of [`BigInt`](https://rust-num.github.io/num/num/struct.BigInt.html) and `BigUint` values and perform some arithmetic operations.

I produced code where I frequently used `BigInt::from(Xu8)` because it is not possible to directly add numbers from different types (if I understand correctly).

I want to reduce the number of `BigInt::from` in my code. I thought about a function to "wrap" this, but I would need a function for each type I want to convert into `BigInt`/`BigUint`:

```
fn short_name(n: X) -> BigInt {
    return BigInt::from(n)
}
```

Where `X` will be each type I want to convert.

I couldn't find any solution that is not in contradiction with the static typing philosophy of Rust.

I feel that I am missing something about traits, but I am not very comfortable with them, and I did not find a solution using them.

Am I trying to do something impossible in Rust? Am I missing an obvious solution?

Comment: By the way, I think that the title of the question is too accurate, I did not know how to write it general enough to cover similar problems, if any of you have a better idea :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`From<T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.From.html) trait (and the complementary [`Into<T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.Into.html) trait) is what is typically used to convert between types in Rust. In fact, the `BigInt::from` method comes from the `From` trait.

You can modify your `short_name` function into a generic function with a `where` clause to accept all types that `BigInt` can be converted from:

```rust
fn short_name<T>(n: T) -> BigInt // function with generic type T
where
    BigInt: From<T>, // where BigInt implements the From<T> trait
{
    BigInt::from(n)
}
```

Comment: `T: Into<BigInt>` is a more relaxed constraint than `BigInt: From<T>`, although it's not likely to make *much* difference.

Answer (score 3):

To answer this part:

> I produced code where I frequently used `BigInt::from(Xu8)` because it is not possible to directly add numbers from different types (if I understand correctly).

On the contrary, if you look at `BigInt`'s documentation you'll see many `impl Add`:

```
impl<'a> Add<BigInt> for &'a u64
impl Add<u8> for BigInt
```

and so on. The first allows calling `a_ref_to_u64 + a_bigint`, the second `a_bigint + an_u8` (and both set `OutputType` to be `BigInt`). You don't need to convert these types to `BigInt` before adding them! And if you want your method to handle any such type you just need an `Add` bound similar to the `From` bound [in Frxstrem's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59329558/155423). Of course if you want many such operations, `From` may end up more readable.

Comment: I was indeed wrong, thank you for correcting me and explaining the error :)